# angular - detect only the directive I've clicked

Tags: angularjs

I have a small directive in my angular app that create a submenu.

In one of my page, I have lots of submenus (one for each element of my list, basically)

I am trying to write a function to detect the position on screen so that I can decide if I wanted to open my submenu upward or downwards.

The function itself seem to work fine if I have only one element on the page, but as soon as I have multiple elements, it breaks, because it is selecting all of the element in all of my directive.

I know it's hard to understand with my poor explanation, so here's some code:

**directive template:**

```
<div class="full-screen-body-overlay" ng-if="showToggleMenu" ng-click="hideRoomSubmenu()"></div>
<div class="submenu" title="submenu">
    <!-- Menu Icon -->
    <div class="submenu-icon">
        <i class="icon"
           ng-class="showToggleMenu ? 'ion-close-round' : icon"
           ng-click="changeIcon()"></i>
    </div>
    <!-- Menu -->
    <div ng-transclude class="list submenu-content" ng-class="showToggleMenu ? 'active' : ''"></div>
</div>
```

**directive js**

```
angular.module('Submenu', []).directive('Menu', [
  function() {
    var detectSubmenuPostion, linkFunction;
    detectSubmenuPostion = function() {
      var $button, $ul, spaceDown, spaceUp, ulOffset;
      $ul = angular.element('.submenu-item');
      $button = angular.element('.submenu-icon');
      ulOffset = $ul.offset();
      spaceUp = ulOffset.top - $button.height() - $ul.height() - $(window).scrollTop();
      spaceDown = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - (ulOffset.top + $ul.height());
      if (spaceDown < 0 && (spaceUp >= 0 || spaceUp > spaceDown)) {
        return $('.submenu-content').addClass('dropup');
      } else {
        return $('.submenu-content').removeClass('dropup');
      }
    };
    linkFunction = function(scope, el, attr) {
      var submenuitem;
      submenuitem = angular.element('.submenu-item');
      $('.submenu-content').removeClass('dropup');
      if (attr.icon != null) {
        scope.icon = attr.icon;
      } else {
        scope.icon = 'ion-more';
      }
      angular.forEach(submenuitem, function(item) {
        var ngClick;
        ngClick = item.attributes['ng-click'];
        if (ngClick && ngClick.value !== '') {
          return angular.element(item).bind('click', function() {
            return scope.showToggleMenu = false;
          });
        }
      });
      scope.showToggleMenu = false;
      scope.changeIcon = function() {
        if (scope.showToggleMenu === false) {
          detectSubmenuPostion();
          return scope.showToggleMenu = true;
        } else {
          return scope.showToggleMenu = false;
        }
      };
      return scope.hideRoomSubmenu = function() {
        if (scope.showToggleMenu === false) {
          return scope.showToggleMenu = true;
        } else {
          return scope.showToggleMenu = false;
        }
      };
    };
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: false,
      transclude: true,
      templateUrl: 'submenu.tpl.html',
      link: linkFunction
    };
  }
]);
```

and here's a fiddle:
http://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/GWPEgJ?editors=0010

If you open the console (apart from the warning saying I am trying to load angular more than once, which is not related to this anyway), and you open one submenu, you can see that $ul (from `detectSubmenuPostion()`) gets all the items for all the menus, and not just the once I just clicked (which is what I am interested in).

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

thanks

Comment: You need to do your dom lookups against the `el` object instead of the whole document. If you have jQuery loaded before angular `el` will be a full jquery object of your directive. Then you can search for just the elements in the scope of your directive.

Comment: Thanks! it seem to work (pretty much) perfectly now!
http://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/GWPEgJ?editors=0010
Is there any whay to avoid having to do.children().children all these times? also, wanna put this as an answer so that I can select it?